# Why is event.currentTarget null in my function?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I was debugging an issue in my JavaScript code with a variable not being properly set. After a little research, I found out that the variable was not being populated because it was taking its value from an event property that didn't exist. In this case, it was deriving its value from `event.currentTarget`, which was strangely null.

So I'm a little baffled now. I always though that `event.currentTarget` always pointed to whatever element held the listener that fired the event.  So under what circumstances would `event.currentTarget` actually be null?

Comment: It would be `undefined` or `null` if you triggered the event programatically or you are using an older IE version.

Comment: Here's an amazing demo showing how and when all these event properties are set: http://liouh.com/jsevents/

Comment: if you not already do i would recommend to use a library like jQuery for event handling to avoid running into problems with the different browsers setting different properties.

Comment: @Felix Kling - I can verify that the event is actually being fired by the user and not by the code. And I am using Firefox as well.

Comment: @ Joseph Silber - Thank you for the demo. I was considering using event.originalTarget, but from my impression, it seems event.currentTarget is the de facto way of figuring out which element the listener belongs to. I'd rather stick to event.currentTarget

Comment: I'm not sure... if you are actually inside the event handler, `this` should refer to the DOM element it is bound to.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem was with the way the event was being handled.  As you can see below, the event object itself was not only to be processed by its respective handler function; it was also going to be processed by another function that was invoked only when an AJAX call that was made in the handler returned successfully.  However, once the success function executes under the AJAX call, the event object loses some of its context, namely its currentTarget property. I presume that the reason why this is is because we're not directly within the scope of the handler once the browser starts executing code within the success function.

```
$('#element').click(function(e) {
    
    // bunch of lines of code here

    $.ajax({
       type: 'POST',
       url: // url,
       ...,
       success: function(response) {

           // more lines of code here

           callAnotherFunction(e);
           // When we invoke the above function, we pass the event in as a 
           // parameter, but the event has already lost some of its context
           // due to scope change.
       }
    });

})
```

Comment: I noticed the same thing. I "fixed" it by not `await`ing the AJAX call before the function using the `event` finished, but that is not always a good solution. I would like to know why this happens, in case I run into this in the future. For the record, `event.currentTarget` was null as soon as the AJAX call completed, and strangely `event.target` was still populated with the same element as when the event was called. I'm using angular, so maybe angular, and in your case jQuery, changed the event?

Comment: Same here when the event is managed after an async operation.

Comment: same problem on my hands, I tried various tricks, but none was succesfull yet -,-

Comment: if you need access to the `currentTarget` you could set it to variable outside of the Ajax call and pass it along to the success method in addition to the event itself.